# Install python packages behind a proxy

Tags: package-management, python, pip

I am trying to install python packages on my PC running on Ubuntu 14.04, and I am behind a proxy. I have been unsuccessful in my attempt.

I have tried the following :

1. **`sudo -E easy_install elm`**

> ```
> Searching for elm
> Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/elm/
> Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/elm/: Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden -- Some packages may not be found!
> Couldn't find index page for 'elm' (maybe misspelled?)
> Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
> Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
> Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden -- Some packages may not be found!
> No local packages or download links found for elm
> error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('elm')
> ```

2. **`sudo -E pip install elm`**

> ```
> Downloading/unpacking elm
>   Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
>   Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement elm
> Cleaning up...
> No distributions at all found for elm
> Storing debug log for failure in /home/guru/.pip/pip.log
> ```

I have set the following environment variables as:

- **http_proxy** `export http_proxy=http://username:password@ProxyServerIP:port`
- **https_proxy** `export https_proxy=https://username:password@ProxyServerIP:port`

Note that all the above links are accessible via browser. I have been using `apt` to install packages by setting my proxy in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and it works great. But, I am not able to figure out what can be done for `pip` or `easy_install`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `pip --proxy=`?

Comment: is user in AD domain? does password contains @&! symbols?

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, I have tried that too with both `http` as well as `https`

Comment: @IvanTemchenko Yes, user is admin, and password contains only alphanumerals.

Comment: then `export http_proxy=http://domain\\username:password@ProxyServerIP:port`

Comment: @IvanTemchenko I didn't quite understand `domain` that you mentioned. I tried using both `user` and `hostname` in place of domain. But still I keep getting the same set of errors.

Comment: oh, Im asking is your user for proxy in Microsoft Active Directory domain?

Comment: @IvanTemchenko Sorry, if I have confused you. My bad. I am not network administrator.  I only have admin rights on my PC, and I am on Ubuntu. How is Microsoft Active Directory domain relevant to me?

Comment: if you are trying to authenticate on proxy, which uses AD account - you must specify the domain for it in exported variable for shell...

Comment: @IvanTemchenko No, mine is not an administrator account on proxy.

Comment: you dont need to be administrator of proxy.  all I'm asking - is your account for internet access (not local) is a Active Directory account? What credentials you'r inputing in brouser for proxy access?

Comment: @IvanTemchenko Once I set, my system's IP (10.0.3.70) which is valid for us, then I set the Manual proxy configuration with the `ProxyServerIP` and `port`, then when I try to connect to internet, I get a pop-up asking for my `username` and `password`. This is how I connect to internet.